# Implementing helper function that uses linq to create a grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

First off, I am new to linq and I sort of get the syntax, but there are some pieces missing, I have no idea how to search for these said pieces as I don't know the terminology, so I have resorted to asking personally. (so please take it easy on me linq has me all turned around)

I wanted to learn by creating something, so I figured an HTML helper that generates a table would be fun to do.

I was looking at other examples and I want to implement something like this, my question is then, what would the parameter for the Columns function be? I am also not quite sure how the columns.Bound are all assigned to columns, maybe columns takes a list of "bound" objects?

```
Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.CustomerViewModel>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.ContactName).Width(140);
            columns.Bound(c => c.ContactTitle).Width(190);
            columns.Bound(c => c.CompanyName);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Country).Width(110);
        })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 380px;" })
        .Scrollable()
        .Groupable()
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("Customers_Read", "Grid"))
        )
```

I can't seem to find a good example explaining a scenario like this. I feel once one is explained, the rest will fall into place.

and my last question is, with the Bound information, how does it use it when it wants to display the information later? I get the concept of binding, just not with linq in particular.

could someone give me a simple example of a helper object that will take a list of columns and their bound values and print them out to a table? It doesn't need to compile or even work, it is just so I can get an idea.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Your Visual Studio intellisense will tell you the parameter type.

Comment: I don't own the code for the one provided, but I am currently looking at it with some other code, I guess I just don't get it completely yet. I don't really know what the { function; function; function; } generates, a list?

Comment: I think those codes showing how to create a grid using Kendo UI. So you need to find documentation about Kendo UI not linq. It is using [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx), so the syntax is similar to lambda expression in linq.

Comment: Well I understand how the functions work, returning a class of the same type to allow chaining and what lambda expressions are (at least the simple definition of it), I just have a bit of trouble understanding how it all goes together, for example why use linq? is it simply shorthand? thanks.

also, that link gave me a name to the statements in the brackets "Statement Lambdas" I seemed to have overlooked it before, thanks again.